# set HTML shown on root SignalR endpoint

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a C# client and server application that communicates using SignalR. The server is a self-hosted executable. It all works fine. When I put the server's endpoint address (aka, `http://blahBlah:18080/`) into a browser, it shows a completely blank page. (That's more than it does when the server isn't running.) However, I would like to reuse that endpoint to display a little bit of status information for the server. How can I specify the HTML to return by that default SignalR endpoint? My server setup is quite simple and listed here:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
{
  EnableDetailedErrors = true,
  EnableJavaScriptProxies = false,
  EnableJSONP = false,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SignalR is not for serving HTML pages. You will need to configure OWin as a file server, in addition to mapping SignalR. From what I can tell, you won't be able to map SignalR and static files to the same directory. For example, you could map `http://bloBlah:18080/` to a filesystem, and map SignalR to `http://bloBlah:18080/signalR`.

First thing is to add `Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles` via NuGet. Then, create a mapping to an index.html file. This code sample is very basic - you'll want to look into the FileServeroptions carefully.

```
var options = new FileServerOptions()
{
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false,
};
options.DefaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames.Add("index.html");
app.UseFileServer(options);
```

These two code samples helped me figure this out:

- http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/Katana/StaticFilesSample/Startup.cs
- http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/10/building-a-simple-file-server-with-owin-and-katana.aspx

Comment: What is the default SignalR mapping created by `app.MapSignalR`? Is it not `http://*/signalr`? Does `UseFileServer` map it to the root by default?

Comment: To be honest I can't remember what the default is for SignalR - I manually mapped it to "/signalr". The default for FileServer is root. There is an option to set a different path, via FileServerOptions. E.g.  options.RequestPath = new PathString("/public")